# Связь трёх таблиц с целостностью данных

Tags: access, ms-access

Скоро сдавать работу а  больше программировать могу чем таблицы делать. Задача есть три таблицы физ лица, юр. лица и есть таблица с договорами в которой есть код арентодателя, как связать таблицы так что бы код арендодателя вел к обоим таблицам, но при этом было обеспечение целостности данных.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам нужна еще одна таблица "Субъекты права", где выдаются общие "коды" физ и юрлицам и там же тип лица. А таблицы физ/юрлица являются ее подчиненными. Ссылка из договоров идет к Субъектам. Ну и можно какие либо общие поля вынести в Субъектов, вот телефоны например, может еще физ адреса появятся, ИНН

Comment: @Mike не знаю как это реализовать что бы Access  не ругался как сделать что бы тип лица на физ юр делился и исходя из этого он таблицу выбирал ?

Comment: Не представляю. с ацессом никогда не сталкивался, я по фуншую реляционных баз говорю как оно было бы правильно. А некий автовыбор это уже скорее прикладная часть. по крайней мере обычно БД сама такое не решает а решает приложение куда и как данные положить, ну либо в БД view делается которая пишет либо в одну либо в другу таблицу (но такие view мало какие БД поддерживают)

Comment: Ну так по логике Вам надо сделать 1-to-many от "лиц" к договорам. Т.е. одно физ.лицо (или юр.лицо) может быть в таблице "лиц" только раз, но может иметь несколько договоров (т.е. повторяться в "договорах"). Минус только в том, что в таблице договоров Вам нужна еще колонка, чтобы знать с кем заключен договор: с физ. или юр. лицом

Answer (score 1):

создайте 4 таблицу и свяжите арендодателя там к 2 другим ключам других таблиц

Comment: ну я создал таблицу Код:Арентодатель:Тип но как провести связи к 2 таблицам из типов